# How to store .txt data permanently within python code?

Tags: python, list, executable

I am writing a script in python that reads a large .txt file and compiles the information in the file into a list. This file needs to be read any time the script is ran, and never changes. Is there some way for me to incorporate this file into my code, such that if other people run the script on their computers, they only need to have the executable, and not both the executable and the .txt file?

I would like to avoid manually entering this .txt file into a list declaration, as this would be very time consuming.

Comment: Assign its contents to a variable as a string & process it the same way you do now.

Comment: You said: "I would like to avoid manually entering this .txt file into a list declaration, as this would be very time consuming." Why not write a one-time (python) script that will spit this out for you?

Comment: Try a `StringIO`, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringio-module-in-python/

Comment: Have a look for [persistence data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid manually entering this .txt file into a list declaration, as this would be very time consuming.

use [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) to print out your resulting list one time. you can configure `pprint` to wrap the list OR keep it compact. the output will look like a list that you can copy into your script and assign to a variable  you never have to process again or include an extra file.

https://onlinegdb.com/CRtyashM4

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file within your project directory to be accessible from the code. In this case, the file simply would stay with your code.

The directory could look like:

```
-project
    - docs
        - file.txt
    - main.py
```

Within your code then you can do:

```
with open(docs/file.txt, 'r') as f:
    # do something with the file
```

Be aware that if you choose this your code is then dependent on your directory structure.

Alternatively, you can simply create a multiline string and paste it into a python file as a var and access it.

Something like:

```
my_file_string = '''some long string'''
# do something with the string
```

I would also like to note that neither of these is the "best" solution strictly speaking, but it's a good way to handle things if you are working fast or on a small project. Given the way you phrased your question, this should solve your issue. Good luck!